# Errors compiling with opencv 4.0.1

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to compile code with opencv 4.0.1, now suddenly errors come up,

```
"/usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2/core/cvstd_wrapper.hpp:45:40: Declaration of constexpr static data member 'check' requires an initializer"

/usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2/core/cvstd_wrapper.hpp:49:22: No matching function for call to object of type 'const std::true_type' (aka 'const integral_constant<bool, (true)>')


/usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2/core/cvstd_wrapper.hpp:61:62: In instantiation of template class 'cv::sfinae::has_parenthesis_operator<cv::DefaultDeleter<cv::detail::PlaneWarper>, void, cv::detail::PlaneWarper *>' requested here

/usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2/core/cvstd_wrapper.hpp:138:21: During template argument deduction for class template partial specialization 'has_custom_delete<type-parameter-0-0, typename enable_if<sfinae::has_parenthesis_operator<DefaultDeleter<T>, void, T *>::value, void>::type>' [with T = cv::detail::PlaneWarper]

/usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2/stitching/warpers.hpp:137:80: In instantiation of function template specialization 'cv::makePtr<cv::detail::PlaneWarper, float>' requested here

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/type_traits:264:31: Candidate function not viable: requires 0 arguments, but 1 was provided
```

But the error is in the opencv file. What to do about this?

Comment: Please copy-paste the full output of the compile command. Use `\`\`\`` on the line before and after your copy-pasted text to properly format this text output.

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: I am using LLVM 8.1 and uses libc++(LLVM C++ standard library with c++ 11 support) as c++ standard library